# regular expression nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

can some answer me to what i have done wrong with regexp. I need to write regexp that pass value from phonenumber only with this these three formats:
"+38 (093) 937-99-92" and "093 937 99 92" and "(093) 937 99 92"

during i have start writing that thing i had an error [example of error and how i do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxrDb.png)

I know about escaping symbols but in my example all symbols i escaped, all other is the part of regular expression as i know ...

```
$.validator.addMethod("phone", function(value, element) {

        return /^\+[0-9]{2}\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}+$/i.test(value);
    }
```

Comment: It's the trailing `+` that's the problem. You will need `(?:[0-9]{3})+`.

Comment: There is a fantastic website/tool called rubular.com -- It has some docs for using regex on the page, however the real gem is the ability to input your regex, sample data, and see how everything parses out. It's super handy for issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

```
^(?:\+[0-9]{2}\s)?(?:\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})\s[0-9]{3}(-|\s)[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will match strings in the following formats

- +38 (093) 937-99-92
- 093 937 99 92
- (093) 937 99 92

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/lM8hS0/1

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \+                       '+'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the trailing `+` that's the problem. You will need something to repeat, eg: `(?:[0-9]{3})+`. But this regex should match your needs:

```
/^(?:\+\d{2} \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}|(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2})$/
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/lD4cQ1/1)

I removed the `^` and `$` (start and end of string) in the linked page, and also added the `g`lobal flag, so that you can see how it works.

Comment: Op says these formats: why you remove begin and end ? better to explaine what is the difference ;-)